What's wrong with my formal translation of "every positive number has exactly two square roots"?
I translated the statement "every positive number has exactly two square roots" as $$\forall x, x>0\implies (\exists!y,\exists!z,y<z\land y^{2}=x\land z^{2}=x).$$
My thinking is that the quantifier $\exists!y$ specifies that the predicate $\exists!z,y<z\land y^{2}=x\land z^{2}=x$ is true for only one $y.$ That is, for only one value of $y$ is it true that for only one value of $z,$ we have that $y,z$ will be distinct roots ($y<z$ rather than $y\neq z$ ensures they cannot be switched).
What's wrong with my translation?

I think the problem is that your sentence only asserts that there are two biggest square roots $y$ and $z$. It does not rule out that some real number has 3 (or more) distinct square roots $t < y < z$.
(edit : renamed to make it consistent with OPs notation)

Right, because $x$ is still unique with the property that $\exists! z. x < z \land \dots$.

Doesn't this violate the uniqueness of the existence?

@DanDan面 no, as I said. The property of $y$ under consideration translates to "$y$ is the second largest root". The second largest root is always unique if it exists, so this doesn't preclude having more than two roots.

The statement doesn't say $y$ is the second largest root though, just that it's smaller than $z$.

I am talking about the statement $P(y) := \exists! z. y < z \land y^2 = x \land z^2 = x$. The variable $z$ isn't free in that statement, so it can't possibly say that. If you read it carefully, you'll find that it says exactly that $y$ is the second largest root.

The statement says that there is only one $y$ which is a root, and for which there is exactly one root $z$ larger than $y$. So this does not prevent that another root $t$ hangs around below $y$.

Whoops, I had read the existence as applying to $y,z$ at the same time. Everything would be OK if the statement read $\exists!(y,z),y<z\dotsc$

Martin has already explained why your formula doesn't say what you want it to say. The usual first-order logic way of expressing that there exactly two solutions would yield the following:
$$\forall x >0 \ \exists y \ \exists z \left (y \neq z \wedge y^2 = x \wedge z^2 = x \wedge (\forall v \quad v^2 = x \Rightarrow (v = y \vee v = z)) \right )$$

Another way of looking at is is, let $S$ be the set of all square roots of $x$.
Then your claim is $\exists! y \in S \exists! z \in S ~ y < z$, or implicitly quantifying over $S$, just
$$\exists! y \exists! z ~ y < z$$
Which is just saying "there is exactly one value for which there is exactly one greater value", but it says nothing of lesser values.
The comment that rewriting it as
$$\exists! (y,z) ~ y < z$$
works is correct, as it is just saying "there is exactly one strictly ordered pair in the domain".
Though, you really shouldn't write things like this to begin with.  If you absolutely must write things symbolically, then
$$\forall x ~~|\{r \text{ s.t. } r^2 = x \}| = 2$$
